# Nodemailer not working with Node v. 10.14.2

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I'm trying to use Nodemailer with Node v. 10.14.2, but it keeps crashing when I run the server. The errormessage implies that the problem is in the source code of Nodemailer:

```
Debugger listening on [::]:15454
/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/mailer/index.js:31
            compile: [(...args) => this._convertDataImages(...args)],
                       ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/nodemailer.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/controllers/mailHandler.server.js:4:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
```

Any suggestions what to do?

Comment: You should add your code too.

Comment: It is better to report this issue, on nodemailer GitHub page, there you may find confirmation.

Comment: Please see [THIS](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/754) and [THIS](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/766)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got great help from J4GD33P 51NGH but can't upvote cause I'm so new on stackexchange. Although I had installed the newest Node, there were multiple versions, and the code was running in an older version.

Got that fixed with the command nvm alias default 10.14.2, so now the code REALLY runs in Node version 10.14.2 and Nodemailer is working.